# Don't click link automatically after calling function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a troublesome feature which probably has been answered somewhere before but i did some searching and brain totally froze. So i have this code:

```
function createTimeLink(){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.id = "link_"+vooru_nr;
    link.textContent = "VOOR "+vooru_nr;
    link.onclick = timeHelper();
    var headrow = document.getElementsByClassName("elem_"+vooru_nr);
    headrow[0].textContent = "";
    headrow[0].appendChild(link);
}

function timeHelper(){
    console.log("clicked");
}
```

I create an element  and try to give an onclick property to it. However if i call out function createTimeLink() in window.onload, "clicked" will be logged in the console but will not be logged each time i click the link again. How could i make it in a manner that if i click my link then something would happen? In future i would like to open a modal after clicking a link but currently it won't even display 'clicked' in console when clicking on the link.

Comment: there needs to be space between the `"link_"` and the attachment you are adding on. put a space between them.

Comment: There is no need to put a space between `"` and `+`. You _can_ do it, and Crockford wants us to do it, but from the JS Syntax itself, there's absolutely nothing wrong with no space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are setting link.onclick to the *RESULT* of a function call. Leave out the parentheses, and it will probably work:

```
link.onclick = timeHelper;
```

In JavaScript, functions are objects, so you can either call them (what you're usually doing with functions, that is what the parentheses do), or pass them around (in that case, you don't write parentheses!).

So these two are very different:

- `someFunction();` (runs the function, returns its result)
- `someFunction;` (does not run the function)

@w3re correctly points out, that `addEventListener` is probably the cleanest approach. It does not change functionality here, but you may encounter examples later, where you would like to have more than one event listener.

If you haven't worked with `addEventListener` and its counterpart `removeEventListener` yet, i'd highly recommend it!

Comment: Registering events through the onclick property is not consindered best practice, it's generally better to use addEventListener.

Comment: Just a quick follow up question, if i create multiple links, how can i later on recognize which one of the links were clicked?

Comment: yes: your function `timeHelper` will be called in the "context" of the element. So INSIDE of timeHelper, you can use the `this` keyword - it should refer to your HTML-Element. Try `alert(this.id);` from within `timeHelper`, it should output you the id of the clicked element.

Answer (score 2):

You're executing timeHelper() and assigning the result of that function to the onclick handler. On top of that, if you're working in JavaScript, the preferred method of adding events is the addEventListener() function.

So, change

```
link.onclick = timeHelper();
```

to

```
link.addEventListener("click", timeHelper);
```

Comment: the `addEventListener` is the cleaner approach. I was aiming for the "least change possible" in my answer. I upvoted yours, because it's also a very good point!